# Atomic Block for reading vs ARM SysTicks

Tags: c, gcc, arm, interrupt-handling, arduino-due

I am currently porting my [DCF77 library](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/dcf77/dcf77-library/) (you may find the [source code at GitHub](https://github.com/udoklein/dcf77_library)) from Arduino (AVR based) to Arduino Due (ARM Cortex M3). I am an absolute beginner with the ARM platform.

With the AVR based Arduino I can use [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html) to get atomic blocks. Basically this blocks all interrupts during the block and will allow interrupts later on again. For the AVR this was fine. Now for the ARM Cortex things start to get complicated.

First of all: for the current uses of the library this approach would work as well. So my first question is: is there someting similar to the "ATOMIC" macros of avr-libc for ARM? Obviously other people have thought of [something in this directions.](http://www.keil.com/forum/12988/atomic-block-intterupts-proof-on-cortex-m3/) Since I am using gcc I could enhance these macors to work almost exactly like the avr-libv ATOMIC macors. I already found some [CMSIS documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABEDCBC.html) however this seems only to provide an "enable_irq" macro instead of a "restore_irq" macro.

Question 1: is there any library out there (for gcc) that already does this?

Because ARM has different priority interrupts I could establish the atomicity in different ways as well. In my case the "atomic" blocks must only make sure that they are not interrupted by the systick interrupt. So actually I would not need to block everything to make my blocks "atomic enough". Searching further I found an [ARM synchronization primitives article in the developer infocenter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/ch01s02s01.html). Especially there is a hint at [lockless programming](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/ch01s03s04.html). According to the article this is an advanced concept and that there are many publications on it. Searching the net I found only general explanations of the concept, e.g. [here](http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/). I assume that a lockless implementation would be very cool but at this time I feel not confident enough on ARM to implement this from scratch.

Question 2: does anyone have some hints for me on lockless reads of memory blocks on ARM Cortex M3?

As I already said I only need to protect the lower priority thread from sysTicks. So another option would be to disable sysTicks briefly. Since I am implementing a timing sensitive clock algorithm this must not slow down the overall sysTick frequency in the long run. Introducing some small jitter would be OK though. At this time I would find this most attractive.

Question 3: is there any good way to block sysTick interrupts without losing any ticks?

I also found the [CMSIS documentation for semaphores](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/RTOS/html/group___c_m_s_i_s___r_t_o_s___semaphore_mgmt.html). However I am somewhat overwhelmed. Especially I am wondering if I should use CMSIS and how to do this on an Arduino Due.

Question 4: What would be my best option? Or where should I continue reading?

Partial Answer:
with the hint from Notlikethat I implemented

```
#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR)
    #include <util/atomic.h>
    #define CRITICAL_SECTION ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)

#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAM)
    // Workaround as suggested by Stackoverflow user "Notlikethat"
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998059/atomic-block-for-reading-vs-arm-systicks

    static inline int __int_disable_irq(void) {
        int primask;
        asm volatile("mrs %0, PRIMASK\n" : "=r"(primask));
        asm volatile("cpsid i\n");
        return primask & 1;
    }

    static inline void __int_restore_irq(int *primask) {
        if (!(*primask)) {
            asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");
            asm volatile("cpsie i\n");
        }
    }
    // This critical section macro borrows heavily from
    // avr-libc util/atomic.h
    // --> http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/atomic_8h_source.html
    #define CRITICAL_SECTION for (int primask_save __attribute__((__cleanup__(__int_restore_irq))) = __int_disable_irq(), __ToDo = 1; __ToDo; __ToDo = 0)

#else
    #error Unsupported controller architecture
#endif
```

This macro does more or less what I need. However I find there is room for improvement as this blocks all interrupts although it would be sufficient to block only systicks. So Question 3 is still open.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `asm volatile("mrs %0, PRIMASK\n" :: "r"(primask));` is bad assembly because it marks the primask variable as an input instead of an output, which will lead GCC to re-use the register. I saw hard faults. Corrected: `asm volatile("mrs %0, PRIMASK\n" : "=r"(primask));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of what you've referenced is about synchronising memory accesses between multiple CPUs, or pre-emptively scheduled threads on the same CPU, which seems entirely inappropriate given the stated situation. "Atomicity" in that sense refers to guaranteeing that when one observer is *updating memory*, any observer *reading memory* sees either the initial state, or the updated state, but never something part-way in between.

"Atomicity" *with respect to interrupts* follows the same principle - i.e. ensuring that if an interrupt occurs, a sequence of code has either not run at all, or run completely - but is a conceptually different thing<sup>1</sup>. There are only two things guaranteed to be atomic w.r.t. interrupts: a single instruction<sup>2</sup>, or a sequence of instructions executed with interrupts disabled.

The "right" way to achieve that is indeed via the `CPSID`/`CPSIE` instructions, which are wrapped in the [`__disable_irq()`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_pge1397111458225.htm)/[`__enable_irq()`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124996163.htm) intrinsics. Note that there are two "stages" of interrupt handling in the system: the M3 core itself only has a single IRQ signal - it's the external NVIC's job to do all the routing/multiplexing/prioritisation of the system IRQs into this one line. When the CPU wants to enter a critical section, all it needs to do is mask its own IRQ input with `CPSID`, do what it needs, then unmask with `CPSIE`, at which point any pending IRQ from the NVIC will be taken immediately.

For the case of nested/re-entrant critical sections, the intrinsics provide a handy `int __disable_irq(void)` form which returns the previous state, so you can unmask conditionally on that.

For other compilers which don't offer such intrinsics, it's straightforward enough to roll your own, e.g.:

```
static inline int disable_irq(void) {
    int primask;
    asm volatile("mrs %0, PRIMASK\n"
                 "cpsid i\n" : "=r"(primask));
    return primask & 1;
}

static inline void enable_irq(int primask) {
    if (primask)
        asm volatile("cpsie i\n");
}
```

---

<sub>[1] One confusing overlap is the latter sense is often used to achieve the former in single-CPU multitasking - if interrupts are off, no other thread can get scheduled until you've finished, thus will never see partially-updated memory.</sub>

<sub>[2] With the possible exception of load/store-multiple instructions - in the low-latency interrupt configuration, these *can* be interrupted, and either restarted or continued upon return.</sub>

Comment: The issue is that the critical sections may be in functions that are also called from within interrupts or other critical sections. Hence I assume that __enable_irq() is not appropriate to end a critical section. How would I ensure that the previous interrupt mask is restored?

Comment: This was the point that I was obviously missing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately I did not miss that point. If I try to access __disable_irq() I get an error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     for (uint8_t was_masked __attribute__((__cleanup__(__iRestore))) = __disable_irq(), __ToDo = 1; __ToDo ; __ToDo = 0)

Obviously the compiler assumes that __disable_irq() will return void.

Comment: Ah, seems I got distracted by all the armcc references and forgot the [gcc] tag - presumably it either needs more specific options to enable the `int` version (like armcc needs --cpu set appropriately) or it just doesn't support it. Either way, I've added a DIY example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `asm volatile("mrs %0, PRIMASK\n" :: "r"(primask));` is bad assembly because it marks the primask variable as an input instead of an output, which will lead GCC to re-use the register. I saw hard faults. Corrected: `asm volatile("mrs %0, PRIMASK\n" : "=r"(primask));`

Comment: @Craig You're quite right, not sure how I managed that. Thanks for pointing it out.